# Почем type.GetProperties() возвращает пустой массив?

Tags: c#, .net, рефлексия

Пытаюсь получить доступ к перечислению через рефлексию. Ожидаю, что `GetProperties()` выдаст массив с моим перечислением. Но вместо этого выдается пустой массив, почему?

```
public enum Test_enum { Sun,Mon,Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat };

Type type = typeof(Test_enum);
PropertyInfo[] properties = _enum.GetProperties();
Console.WriteLine("arr length " + properties.Length);
```

Comment: потому что это не свойства?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Когда вы объявляете перечисление, компилятор генерирует подобный [IL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language):

```
.class private auto ansi sealed Test_enum
       extends [mscorlib]System.Enum
{
  .field public specialname rtspecialname int32 value__
  .field public static literal valuetype Test_enum Sun = int32(0x00000000)
  .field public static literal valuetype Test_enum Mon = int32(0x00000001)

  ...
} // end of class Test_enum
```

Что будет соответствовать примерно такому классу:

```
sealed class Test_enum : System.Enum
{
    public const Test_enum Sun = 0;
    public const Test_enum Mon = 1;

    ...
}
```

Как видите, каждый член вашего перечисления является *константой*, а не свойством. Достать эти константы можно при помощи рефлексии:

```
var fields = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);

foreach (var field in fields)
{
    if (field.IsLiteral && !field.IsInitOnly)
    {
        // Искомая константа
    }
}
```

Где [`IsLiteral`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.isliteral(v=vs.110).aspx) указывает, что поле не может быть изменено, а [`IsInitOnly`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.isinitonly(v=vs.110).aspx) показывает, что значение поля можно установить только в конструкторе (`readonly`)

---

Что бы не было недопонимания, [`Enum.GetNames`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.enum.getnames(v=vs.110).aspx) внутри использует [такой-же механизм](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/enum.cs,522) рефлекcии, что делает код выше избыточным во многих случаях.

Comment: Большое спасибо, теперь понял. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
Enum.GetNames(typeof(Test_enum));
Enum.GetValues(typeof(Test_enum));
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ну вы бы хоть объяснили или сослались на документацию.

Comment: Вопрос скорее про рефлексию, а не про перечисления.

Comment: @Alex вопрос про получение значений из Enum через рефлексию. Enum.GetValues - это рефлексия